# some settings on android

Tags: android, settings

I want to read the following settings set by the user on the device in my android app(android 4.0+):

1. if Notifications are enabled
2. if 'Encrypt phone' is enabled
3. find the limit on the number of text and Multimedia messages.

Any help or leads would be wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: Use the shared preferences and the settings: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: but shared pref dont allow me to check the general device settings do they? they are app sepcific settings, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, notifications are specific to applications. You can only disable or enable them for each application on Android 4.1 and above.

For Encryption status, you may use [getStorageEncryptionStatus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getStorageEncryptionStatus%28%29) in [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html).

Comment: Hey thanku very much! Those are the kind of methods from the Android API that I am looking for :)

Comment: I dont want to enable or disable the notifications via my app. i just want to check the standard device setting. i want to know whether the notifications that come on the locked device screen are allowed by the user. Is there any API that lets me check that setting?

Comment: @meghna, Notifications can be disabled on app basis. There is no general setting to disable or enable notifications for everything, as far as I know. At least I haven't heard of such setting in Android.